# How to fix "VM error: invalid opcode. invalid opcode"

Tags: solidity

I am trying to create a function called join that lets players join the game . Each time before someone joins the game. the function will check if this player is already exist, if he/she exists in the game, the function will automatically topup the balance of that particular player. Otherwise the function will add the new player to a mapping object called players. But when I try to run the function in remix it returns an error as following:

```
VM error: invalid opcode.
       invalid opcode   
       The execution might have thrown.
       Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

Following is my code:

````
    pragma solidity >=0.5.0;


    contract lotteryAdvanced {
        address public manager;
        mapping(address=>uint) public players;
        uint public totalAmount = 0;
        uint public numPlayers = 0;
        address[] public users;
        modifier managerOnly() {
            require(msg.sender == manager, 'You are not the manager of this game');
            _;
        }
        constructor() public{
            manager = msg.sender;
        }


        function join() public payable{
            require(msg.value >= 100000000000000000 wei, 'Please enter a number within the provided range');
            for( uint i = 0; i <= uint(users.length) ; i++)
            {
              if(msg.sender == users[i]) {
                players[msg.sender] = players[msg.sender] + msg.value;
              }
              players[msg.sender] = msg.value;
              users.push(msg.sender);
            }
            numPlayers++;
        }
    ```
````

Answer (score 1):

This may not solve your immediate problem with Remix / EVM, but—looking at the code you shared—it seems you have a few lines inside of your `for` loop that ought to be outside, and executed conditionally:

```
for(uint i = 0; i <= uint(users.length); i++)
{
    if(msg.sender == users[i]) {
        players[msg.sender] = players[msg.sender] + msg.value;
    }
    players[msg.sender] = msg.value;
    users.push(msg.sender);
}
```

Here, you are writing `msg.value` as the entry for `players[msg.sender]` once for every existing player in `players[]`; you then push `msg.sender` into `users` once for every player. This causes the following to happen:

1. The value of `players[msg.sender]` will always be `msg.value`, even in the scenario where `msg.sender` is already an entry in `players` (i.e., even when this particular player is already in the game). You effectively overwrite your "topping up" code in the preceding `if` block.
2. You end up with `n+1` copies of `msg.sender` inside `users`, where `n` is the number of users that exist (in `users[]`) when `join()` was called.

I would step through each line of your `join()` code and verify that it's performing exactly the steps you expect. You may be able to avoid the `for` loop (which may be "unbounded"—see [this definition](https://blog.b9lab.com/getting-loopy-with-solidity-1d51794622ad)) by modeling `users` as a mapping instead of as an array, and maintaining a separate `usersCount` state variable. This would let you update your `players` mapping in constant time—minimizing your gas costs.

Answer (score 0):

You have the players[] array which is of type address and msg.value which is of type uint256.
I can see a line of code  players[msg.sender] = players[msg.sender] + msg.value; in your for loop whereby you concatenate different variable types. What I think is that you should create a new variable type of uint256 called balance and create a mapping of this new variable to each player in the players[] array.
I am relatively new to this too so correct me if I am wrong